# In Haskell, does the GHC option "-with-rtsopts=-N" optimize for number of cores in the machine compiling program or the machine running the program?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, compiler-optimization, ghc

Does the GHC option `-with-rtsopts=-N` set the number of capabilities  to the number of CPU cores available when compiling the program or more generally to any number of cores that are available when the program is running on any given machine of the same target ISA?

Comment: It should be the latter. Try running your executable with `./my_exe +RTS --info` to check which flags were linked into it.

Comment: I'm not even sure there is anything to optimize there. What optimizations are you talking about?

Comment: Then the @chi comment is the answer.